# Integers, Pointers and Block in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to figure out the memory presentation of OCaml.

What I know are:

1. Integers and Pointers are both one word size (32 bits) with lowest bit set to distinguish
2. Block is used to box more complicated data, such as records, etc.

I got just a bit uncertain about the relationships between them, so ask here for confirmation.

---

```
type r1_t = {foo : int;}

type r2_t = {bar : r1_t;}

let _ = let x = 1 in let r1 = {foo = x} in {bar = r1}
```

in the example above, Here are my understanding:

- `x` is an integer
- `{foo = x}` is a block
- Inside `{foo = x}`, foo is an integer with direct value of x (foo doesn't refer to x's address)
- `{bar = r1}` is also a block
- Inside `{bar = r1}`, bar's value is an pointer, and it refers to the address of `{foo = 1}`

---

Am I correct?

Comment: Take a look at https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/memory-representation-of-values.html, which covers the subject very nicely.

Comment: @gsg yes, I read it and started to get confused for a bit

Comment: You can use the functions in the `Obj` module to inspect values and check whether they're block or not, for instance: `Obj.repr r1 |> Obj.is_block`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also a 64-bit memory model for OCaml.

Mixing ints and pointers in the same description doesn't make sense. There are ints in OCaml, but no pointers per se. They're an implementation detail. The low bit of a pointer is not set; in fact this is the reason that the low bit of an int is set--to distinguish from a pointer.

Your description otherwise looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the manual (section on bindings) and [A beginners guide to OCaml internals](http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/ocaml-internals/).